# Add error message after redirect to a page in controller magento 1.9

Tags: php, magento, controller

I am trying to add error message / success message after redirecting to a page in controller in magento. But the messages are not showing in the next rendered page.

```
Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Error message.');
$this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getUrl('module/index/action'));
```

Answer (score 0):

> the messages block displays all flash messages that are held in the
>   session

you've set a session's message but apparently you don't have a message block for it to appear in.
Include this line of code in the layout, where you would like the message to appear.

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
```

Comment: Actually I have placed that code already. but its still not showing.